# SQL not returning all the output it should

Tags: sql

Customer C should have 2 checkout items with the same Checkout ID.but Customer C only has 1 row returned, not the 2 rows that it should. Why is this so?

There should be another row where Customer C have the same checkout on item 2 with 2 quantity. I doubt its a database issue but I don't see any fault with the where clause either (should have both Brand B & C, not just C):

```
-- Generating data for tables
-- Insert data into the Store table
INSERT INTO Store (Store_ID, Store_Location) VALUES
(1, 'Location A'),
(2, 'Location B'),
(3, 'Location C'),
(4, 'Location D'),
(5, 'Location E'),
(6, 'Location F');

-- Insert data into the Employee table
INSERT INTO Employee (Employee_ID, EmpName, SSN, Phone, StoreRef_ID, Address, PayType, [Password], Manager, Email, Date_hired, Date_Start, Date_End, pay) VALUES
(1, 'John Doe', 12345679, 98543210, 3, 'Address 1', 1, 'password', NUll, 'john@example.com', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', NULL, 10.00),
(2, 'Jane Smith', 98765431, 12567890, 2, 'Address 2', 0, 'password123', 1, 'jane@example.com', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', NULL, 9.00),
(3, 'Robert Johnson', 45678912, 45678901, 1, 'Address 3', 1, 'pass123', Null, 'robert@example.com', '2022-03-01', '2022-03-01', NULL, 8000.00),
(4, 'Sarah Williams', 78912345, 78901234, 5, 'Address 4', 0, 'password456', 3, 'sarah@example.com', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', NULL, 12.00),
(5, 'Michael Brown', 12345678, 98765432, 4, 'Address 5', 1, 'pass567', NUll, 'michael@example.com', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-01', NULL, 11000.00),
(6, 'Emily Davis', 87654321, 10987654, 6, 'Address 6', 0, 'pass890', 5, 'emily@example.com', '2022-06-01', '2022-06-01', NULL, 15.00);
--(7, 'Jamie Tatum', 75655757,19982334,1,'Address 7',1,'pass123',Null,'Jamie@example.com','2022-07-01','2022-07-01',Null,9000.00);

-- Insert data into the Manager table
INSERT INTO Manager (Employee_ID, EmpName, Director) VALUES
(1,'John Doe',1),
(3,'Robert Johnson' ,0),
(5,'Michael Brown' ,0);
--(7, 'Jamie Tatum', 1);

-- Insert data into the Manager_Store table(For Director)
INSERT INTO Manager_Store (Employee_ID, Store_ID)
VALUES (1, 3), (1, 2),(1, 5), (1, 6);
  --      (7,3),(7,5);

-- Insert data into the Checkout table
INSERT INTO Checkout (Checkout_ID, Total_Cost, Transaction_Date) VALUES
(1, 10.99, '2023-05-25 09:15:00'),
(2, 20.99, '2023-02-10 18:30:45'),
(3, 5.99, '2023-07-01 12:00:00'),
(4, 15.99, '2023-06-15 14:30:00'),
(5, 25.99, '2023-04-20 10:45:00'),
(6, 8.99, '2023-03-05 16:20:00');

-- Insert data into the Cashier table
INSERT INTO Cashier (Employee_ID, EmpName, Checkout_ID, Date_hired, [Password Change]) VALUES
(2,'Jane Smith', 1, '2022-02-01', 'password123'),
(4,'Sarah Williams',3, '2022-04-01', 'password456'),
(6,'Emily Davis',5, '2022-06-01', 'pass890');

-- Insert data into the Dependent table
INSERT INTO Dependent (Dependent_ID, Employee_ID, Name, Relationship) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Child A', 'Child'),
(2, 1, 'Spouse A', 'Spouse'),
(3, 2, 'Child B', 'Child'),
(4, 3, 'Child C', 'Child'),
(5, 4, 'Child D', 'Child'),
(6, 4, 'Child E', 'Child');

-- Insert data into the Item table
INSERT INTO Item (Item_ID, Brand, Description, Price, Cost, Shape, Size, UPC, Weight, Taxable) VALUES
(1, 'Brand A', 'Item A', 10.99, 5.99, 'Shape A', 'Size A', 123456789, 0.5, 1),
(2, 'Brand B', 'Item B', 20.99, 15.99, 'Shape B', 'Size B', 987654321, 1.0, 1),
(3, 'Brand C', 'Item C', 5.99, 3.99, 'Shape C', 'Size C', 246813579, 0.25, 0),
(4, 'Brand D', 'Item D', 15.99, 10.99, 'Shape D', 'Size D', 135792468, 0.75, 1),
(5, 'Brand E', 'Item E', 8.99, 4.99, 'Shape E', 'Size E', 369258147, 0.4, 0),
(6, 'Brand F', 'Item F', 12.99, 8.99, 'Shape F', 'Size F', 951753864, 0.9, 1);

-- Insert data into the Inventory table
INSERT INTO Inventory (Inventory_ID, Item_ID, Store_ID, Quantity) VALUES
(1, 2, 2, 50),
(2, 3, 1, 30),
(3, 1, 3, 20),
(4, 4, 4, 40),
(5, 5, 5, 25),
(6, 6, 6, 35),
(7, 1, 4, 15),
(8, 5, 2, 15),
(9, 5, 4, 55);

-- Insert data into the Inventory_Checkout table
INSERT INTO InventoryCheckout (Inventory_ID, Checkout_ID, Quantity) VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(2, 3, 3),
(4, 4, 2),
(5, 5, 1),
(6, 6, 3);

-- Insert data into the Customer table
INSERT INTO Customer (Customer_ID, Checkout_ID, CustName, Phone, Email, Date_Joined) VALUES
(1, 2, 'Customer A', 98765432, 'customerA@example.com', '2022-01-01'),
(2, 3, 'Customer B', 12345670, 'customerB@example.com', '2022-02-01'),
(3, 1, 'Customer C', 45678901, 'customerC@example.com', '2022-03-01'),
(4, 4, 'Customer D', 78901234, 'customerD@example.com', '2022-04-01'),
(5, 5, 'Customer E', 24681357, 'customerE@example.com', '2022-05-01'),
(6, 6, 'Customer F', 13579248, 'customerF@example.com', '2022-06-01');
```

These are my insert statements.

This is my query:

```
SELECT C.CustName          AS 'Customer Name',
       S.Store_ID          AS 'Store_ID',
       S.Store_Location    AS 'Store Address',
       M.EmpName           AS 'Manager of the store',
       CH.Transaction_Date AS 'Transaction Date',
       Itm.Brand           AS 'Brand',
       Itm.Description     AS 'Description',
       IC.Quantity         AS 'Quantity Purchased',
       Cash.EmpName        AS 'Served By'
FROM Customer          AS C, 
     Checkout          AS CH, 
     InventoryCheckout AS IC, 
     Inventory         AS Ivty, 
     Store             AS S,
     Employee          AS E, 
     Manager           AS M, 
     Cashier           AS Cash, 
     Item              AS Itm
WHERE C.Checkout_ID = CH.Checkout_ID 
  AND CH.Checkout_ID = IC.Checkout_ID 
  AND IC.Inventory_ID = Ivty.Inventory_ID 
  AND Ivty.Store_ID = S.Store_ID 
  AND S.Store_ID = E.StoreRef_ID 
  AND E.Employee_ID = M.Employee_ID 
  AND CH.Checkout_ID = Cash.Checkout_ID 
  AND Ivty.Item_ID = Itm.Item_ID;
```

[image]

Comment: All your tables are joined via the where clause, and they are all equivalent to `INNER JOINS` so matching data MUST be found in ALL tables to produce a final result row.  Stop using commas between table names - this will force you to consider the best way to join each table. Remember, **no commas between table names** in the from clause.

Comment: Why are you not using [proper joins introduced into the sql standard over 30 years ago?](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 4):

In 1992 SQL-92 was introduced, it contained "explicit join syntax". That's a tad over 30 years ago! It is time for you to **CEASE** using the where clause as the way to join tables together. This will become more apparent when you see the joins needed to locate all the rows you need because there is some missing data. The point is that you **need** some `LEFT OUTER JOINS` (I have used "left join" as the outer word is optional) to see all the data.

So, CEASE placing commas between table names, instead of the comma specify the type of join. Then, instead of using there where clause for the joining condition just put that after each table.

```
SELECT
      C.CustName AS 'Customer Name'
    , S.Store_ID AS 'Store_ID'
    , S.Store_Location AS 'Store Address'
    , M.EmpName AS 'Manager of the store'
    , CH.Transaction_Date AS 'Transaction Date'
    , Itm.Brand AS 'Brand'
    , Itm.Description AS 'Description'
    , IC.Quantity AS 'Quantity Purchased'
    , Cash.EmpName AS 'Served By'
FROM Customer AS C
INNER JOIN Checkout AS CH ON C.Checkout_ID = CH.Checkout_ID
LEFT  JOIN InventoryCheckout AS IC ON CH.Checkout_ID = IC.Checkout_ID
LEFT  JOIN Inventory AS Ivty ON IC.Inventory_ID = Ivty.Inventory_ID
INNER JOIN Store AS S ON Ivty.Store_ID = S.Store_ID
INNER JOIN Employee AS E ON S.Store_ID = E.StoreRef_ID
LEFT  JOIN Manager AS M ON E.Employee_ID = M.Employee_ID
LEFT  JOIN Cashier AS Cash ON CH.Checkout_ID = Cash.Checkout_ID
INNER JOIN Item AS Itm ON Ivty.Item_ID = Itm.Item_ID;
```

| Customer Name | Store_ID | Store Address | Manager of the store | Transaction Date | Brand | Description | Quantity Purchased | Served By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer B | 1 | Location A | Robert Johnson | 2023-07-01 12:00:00.000 | Brand C | Item C | 3 | Sarah Williams |
| Customer C | 2 | Location B | *null* | 2023-05-25 09:15:00.000 | Brand B | Item B | 2 | Jane Smith |
| Customer C | 1 | Location A | Robert Johnson | 2023-05-25 09:15:00.000 | Brand C | Item C | 3 | Jane Smith |
| Customer D | 4 | Location D | Michael Brown | 2023-06-15 14:30:00.000 | Brand D | Item D | 2 | *null* |
| Customer E | 5 | Location E | *null* | 2023-04-20 10:45:00.000 | Brand E | Item E | 1 | Emily Davis |
| Customer F | 6 | Location F | *null* | 2023-03-05 16:20:00.000 | Brand F | Item F | 3 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b2BM5O4X)

By the way. I have no idea which dbms you actually use, and it would have been useful to provide the DDL (or supply a fiddle).

**Tip**: To start re-factoring your query - reformat it so everything is on a new line. I used [poorsql for that](http://poorsql.com/?inputString=SELECT+C.CustName+AS+%27Customer+Name%27%0A++++%2C+S.Store_ID+AS+%27Store_ID%27%0A++++%2C+S.Store_Location+AS+%27Store+Address%27%0A++++%2C+M.EmpName+AS+%27Manager+of+the+store%27%0A++++%2C+CH.Transaction_Date+AS+%27Transaction+Date%27%0A++++%2C+Itm.Brand+AS+%27Brand%27%0A++++%2C+Itm.Description+AS+%27Description%27%0A++++%2C+IC.Quantity+AS+%27Quantity+Purchased%27%0A++++%2C+Cash.EmpName+AS+%27Served+By%27%0AFROM+Customer+AS+C+%0A++++%2C+Checkout+AS+CH%0A++++%2C+InventoryCheckout+AS+IC%0A++++%2C+Inventory+AS+Ivty%0A++++%2C+Store+AS+S%0A++++%2C+Employee+AS+E%0A++++%2C+Manager+AS+M%0A++++%2C+Cashier+AS+Cash%0A++++%2C+Item+AS+Itm%0AWHERE+C.Checkout_ID+%3D+CH.Checkout_ID%0A++++AND+CH.Checkout_ID+%3D+IC.Checkout_ID%0A++++AND+IC.Inventory_ID+%3D+Ivty.Inventory_ID%0A++++AND+Ivty.Store_ID+%3D+S.Store_ID%0A++++AND+S.Store_ID+%3D+E.StoreRef_ID%0A++++AND+E.Employee_ID+%3D+M.Employee_ID%0A++++AND+CH.Checkout_ID+%3D+Cash.Checkout_ID%0A++++AND+Ivty.Item_ID+%3D+Itm.Item_ID%3B&expandCommaLists=true&trailingCommas=false&spaceAfterExpandedComma=true&expandBooleanExpressions=true&expandCaseStatements=false&expandBetweenConditions=false&expandInLists=false&breakJoinOnSections=false&uppercaseKeywords=true&coloring=true&keywordStandardization=false&randomizeColor=false&randomizeLineLengths=false&randomizeKeywordCase=false&preserveComments=false&enableKeywordSubstitution=false&formattingType=standard&indent=%5Cs%5Cs%5Cs%5Cs&spacesPerTab=4&maxLineWidth=999&statementBreaks=2&clauseBreaks=1&language=&reFormat=true&obfuscate=false) take a note of the options I use on the right panel, putting commas at the start of a line really helps this process.

Then cut & paste the where clause elements that actually join tables together e.g.

```
FROM Customer AS C 
    , Checkout AS CH WHERE C.Checkout_ID = CH.Checkout_ID
    , InventoryCheckout AS IC     AND CH.Checkout_ID = IC.Checkout_ID
    , Inventory AS Ivty     AND IC.Inventory_ID = Ivty.Inventory_ID
    , Store AS S     AND Ivty.Store_ID = S.Store_ID
    , Employee AS E     AND S.Store_ID = E.StoreRef_ID
    , Manager AS M     AND E.Employee_ID = M.Employee_ID
    , Cashier AS Cash     AND CH.Checkout_ID = Cash.Checkout_ID
    , Item AS Itm     AND Ivty.Item_ID = Itm.Item_ID;
```

Then change the commas to JOIN and change WHERE/AND to ON. Check your work at poorsql again. Voila, a SQL-92 variant of your query. Now introduce INNER or LEFT in front of each join to figure out what is holding back your desired result.